# ScrollView does not scroll the child completely

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_buyproduct"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="Make a purchase"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_buyproduct">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".activity.BuyProduct">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="@string/message_unipop"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                //MORE CODE
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't understand why the scrollview does not scroll completely. It misses showing the last two things but they are inside the scrollview so I don't get what is the problem. As you can see in this picture, I can scroll but not to the end of the layout. What could it be?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You may need to set layout_height="0dp" and specify bottom constraint. Then the height of ScrollView would be adjusted appropriately so it could be scrolled to the end.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_buyproduct">

    :

</ScrollView>
```